# Disconnect between Cox Proportional Hazard Model and Output of Coxph()?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm in the process of conducting a Survival Analysis in R, but I want to better understand exactly how the coxph function in the "survival" library calculates the hazard rate for a single observation. My understanding is that the Cox Proportional Hazard model has a regression in the form:

h(t) = h0(t) * e ^ (ßX)

where h0(t) is the baseline hazard rate, ß is a vector of coefficients in the regression, and X is a vector of the variables in the model.

The model is defined in the following call:

```
mod.timed <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ revenue + c_months + pct_month_change + lmr + c_declines, data = big_spenders.long, method = "breslow")
```

This yields the following coefficients:

- revenue:  -3.364925e-06
- c_months: -1.841606e-01
- pct_month_change: -1.080881e-02
- lmr: 1.001214e-06
- c_declines: 3.762748e-01

I've performed the following call to survexp() to get the expected survival rate for each observation in my data set:

```
test_surv <- survexp(event ~ revenue + c_months + pct_month_change + lmr + c_declines, ratetable=mod.timed, data = big_spenders.long, cohort = FALSE)
```

Which is all well and good, except when I try to recreate the output of survexp() for the following example:

- revenue:  22333.55
- c_months: 16
- pct_month_change: .8999741
- lmr: 11754.66
- c_declines: 0

The output from test_surv is the survival rate, so I take 1 - test_surv[observation] to get the hazard rate of .0002783463. When I try to replicate this result using the two functions I've written below, however:

```
  get_vars <- function(observation, model){
  vars <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(model$coefficients))
  cfs <- names(model$coefficients)
  for(i in 1:length(cfs)){
    vars[i] <- observation[1, which(names(observation) == cfs[i])]
  }
  vars
}

hazard_rate <- function(time, observation, model){
  baseline <- basehaz(model, centered = TRUE)

  cfs <- unname(model$coefficients)

  vars <- get_vars(observation, model)

  hazard_rate <- baseline[[1]][time] * exp(sum(vars * cfs))

  hazard_rate
}
```

The result from my own function, however, is 0.0006081559. Although I don't doubt that the output from survexp() is correct, I want to understand exactly why the output from survexp() differs from my calculations (which I've also worked out by hand). What is the call to survexp() doing that I'm not expecting it to? Any comments or feedback on this approach / subject are greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you post a question with no data it an implicit demand that we make up a dataset. Many of us think this is your responsibility and will essentially wait on the sidelines until you do so. On way to sidestep this is to construct examples using datasets from the packages, in this case from pkg-survival. You will improve your understanding of survival analusis if you don't talk about "survival rate" when your really mean "survival" or "survival proportion", and not use "hazard rate" when you really mean "cumulative hazard". Rates are counts of events divided by time.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on semantics. I don't think you should need any data for this question, however, because I'm really more interested in how the implementation of survexp() differs from my hazard_rate function (which, as you point out, should really be called cumulative_hazard_rate, or something along those lines.)

Comment: I don't need data if you don't need an illustration. Persons who want to be clear in discussing survival analysis will not use "rate" when talking about cumulative hazards. The (instantaneous) hazard IS a rate. The integrated (or cumulative) hazard is Not. If all you want is a discussion about algorithms,  then perhaps you should delete the question here and repost on CrossValidated.com where you can ask non-coding questions about algorithmic issues. Here we do coding with data.